# find start of line then compare value in line output filename

Tags: python

I have multiple .txt files with names like try_1, try_2, try_3 etc.
each of file is like

```
$somecontent
1somecontent
somecontent
$
0
1
1
1
0
00
somecontent
somecontent
x2 = 3.6235
z2 = 0.1036
F_eroie = 0.6156
someothervali = 0.9976
somecontent
Some_t2 = 0.8456
---------------------------------
somecontent
somecontent
$

$

$somecontent
```

the only similarity in any file is that all of them contains value of x2, z2, F_eroie, some_t2. I am only interested to know the the filenames of only those file which have values for x2,z2 and some_t2 >=0.5

this is latest code I am trying to work

```
import glob

for i in xrange(50):
       f=open("try_[i].txt",'r')
       for line in f:
               if (x2 >= 0.6 and z2 >= 0.5 and some_t2 >= 0.6):
                       print '%s'% f.filename[i]
                       f.close()
```

another one is

```
with open('try_[i].txt') as infp:
   for line in infp:
      line = line.strip()
      if line.startswith('x2'):
              if x2 >=0.6:
                      if line.startswith('z2'):
                              if z2 >=0.5:
                                      if line.startswith('some_t2'):
                                              if some_t2 >=0.6:
                                                      print '%s'% f.filename[i]
                                                      f.close()
```

both are working in same way (previously another code it was reading line as text as a whole now it is treating x2, z2, and some_t2 as variable )

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are the parentheses ('{' and '}') in your question? I find them confusing and suspect they don't need to be there.  You don't need (or want) them in Python code.  To mark off code in your question all you need to do is indent the text 4 spaces, which it looks like you've done.

Comment: I want know those filenames which have value of x2 and z2 and some_t2 more than or equal to 0.5. or to know whether  it is possible or not. I think there should be way to do it.

Comment: No, PTBNL those parenthses come when I was trying to write code in SO. I will delete them. Deleted

Comment: Upto how many files do you have? There's a better and prettier alternative I'd suggest based on that...

Comment: And can there be more variables other than x2, z2 and some_t2?

Comment: There are _lots_ of errors in your code. Python errors, like using undefined variables, and logic errors, like basically checking thether all of those are on the same line...

Comment: Hello,Aditya I have lakhs of files.  Yes,  every file has no. of other variables. Each variable came once in a file. I only want to filter/know names of files on the basis of x2, z2 and some_t2.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend searching for variables using regular expressions rather than creating stairway to heaven using if-elses. This snippet extracts such variables from a file and returns a python dictionary with stuff like {x2 : 3.625, ...}

```
regexPattern = "(\w+) = (\d.\d+)"

def extractVarsFromFile(filepath):
    variables = {}
    data = open(filepath).readlines()
    for line in data:
        srch = re.search(regexPattern, line, re.MULTILINE)
        if srch:
             results = srch.groups()
             variables[results[0]] = results[1]
    return variables
```

Make it a habit to write reusable and configurable code. Anyone can copy this method and use for related purposes without having to worry about how it works (though it is quite simple).

So here I'm searching for a regular expression pattern that looks like a variable declaration line. If it is found, I'm collecting and returning the values of all the variables. Then I'm using another functino that will process these variables according to your requirements.

```
def check_variable_rules(filepath, minimum=0.5):
    variables = extractVarsFromFile("numbers.txt")
    try:
        return float(ariables['x2'])>=minimum and float(variables['z2'])>=minimum and float(variables['some_t2']) >=minimum
    except:
        logging.warning("One or more of the requested variables are missing")
        return False
```

Just call this function print check_variable_rules("try_00.txt"). If it returns True, your variables follow the rule, otherwise they don't. You can easily configure the function internals to change the rules or change the parameter.

The example you shared checks different conditions. Here's another equally easy and beautiful tweak to the function that also allows you to modify the conditions:

```
def check_variable_rules(filepath, minimum_vals={'x2':0.6, 'z2':0.5, 'some_t2':0.6}):
    variables = extractVarsFromFile("numbers.txt")
    try:
        for min in minimum_vals.keys():
            if float(variables[min]) < float(minimum_vals[min]):
                return False
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

How to use? Just a one liner:

```
if check_variable_rules("numbers.txt"):
    print "Acceptable. Do what you want with the file"
else:
    print "Variables have lower values"
```